# Disable Tooltips in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Hovering over every piece of text in my C# files pops up a "tip". Does anyone know how to remove these tips? Bonus points if you can tell me how to globally remove all tool tips from every window in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio does not have a setting to turn off tooltips, however, you may download
[this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ToggleEditorTooltips#:%7E:text=To%20toggle%20the%20tooltips%20on,will%20reflect%20the%20new%20state.) made by [Mads Kristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/MadsKristensen) that adds a toggle to turn on/off tooltips.

Then do the following :

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- Search for *tooltip*
- Click *Toggle Tooltips* in search result

Comment: I tried both Tame Visual Studio Editor Tooltips and Toggle Editor Tooltips. They both did what I was looking for.

Comment: Plugin won't install for me :( Say's it can't find the .json inside the zip. But it isn't a zip file, it's a visx