# Disable Tooltips in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio

As the Windows version of Visual Studio 2019 extensions cannot be installed in the mac version this [Disable Tooltips in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142641/disable-tooltips-in-visual-studio-2019) is not an option for "VS for Mac" users

Also in the current MonoDevelop AddOns repositories, I couldn't find anything useful, I'd be curious if there's any solution to disable the extremely annoying tooltips in VS for Mac?