# Turn off this quick-info -like UI feature off in VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 (v 17.3.6), I would like to be able

1. Identify this UI hint/tooltip/feature of the C# editor.  It comes up merely when hovering
   over anything/everything, and clutters up the screen greatly.
2. Partially turn it off.  In particular I would like to see this only after I have
   pressed a hot key/chord or clicked, etc.  In other words, I only want it to appear once I have done something more "active"
   than merely hovering the mouse over the code.
   [image]

I searched google, and Tools > Options in VS2022.  I have tried all the options that make
mention of IntelliSense, "quick info", and "inline hints", turning each off in turn.
Nothing seems to turn off.  I would like an in-VS solution if there is one, rather than yet another VSIX package that does other things I don't want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142641/disable-tooltips-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Thanks.  Would like to find an option built-in rather than a VSIX solution, if possible.  Question updated to add that qualification.  But if that's the only way, I may have to with it.