Visual Studio 2022 does not show type info while debugging
When i hover on the type or identificator in debugging mode i can't see its information via type:

How to enable it on?
After settings reset still does not show:


Export/Backup your VS Settings then do a Reset - and/or run VS in safe-mode - and see if it still happens.

Your new screenshot shows a data-tip, VS shows these when you're debugging - it still shows you type-information (that's on the right-side) - but I think you can still have quick-info tooltips in debug mode - just press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+I. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607342/turn-off-this-quick-info-like-ui-feature-off-in-vs2022

@Dai, god damn right.
There is no option to not to do it manually?

I guess it could be by-design as you can use data-tip to view data values in debug mode.You can report your issue on Visual Studio forum to get their help.

I think it could be by-design. But you could submit a feature request at:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
